# what is difference: "She didn't even bother to ask me" & "She wasn't even bothering to ask me"

Tags: grammar, meaning

what is difference: "She **didn't** even **bother** to ask me" &  "She **wasn't** even **bothering** to ask me". 
Thank you.

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
grammar rules and examples 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference. For example [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case with expressions of aspect in English (perfect, continuous), the difference is not in the objective facts, but purely in how the speaker is choosing to present them in time.

If the speaker says "She wasn't even bothering", they are choosing to present the period when she might have bothered as an extended period, and positioning the temporal focus within it. With "She didn't even bother", they are not setting a temporal focus, but just treating the not-bothering as a single event.

As to why they might do this: perhaps to make the story more immediate; or perhaps because they were going to continue talking about the time when she wasn't bothering. There are different possible motives.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I can use both expressions in daily life? Which one is more commonly used? Thanks again.

Comment: Try to find examples on the internet, you will see which one is used more often.

Comment: Yes, you can use both in daily life. I should think that the simple past is more frequent than the other, but I don't really know. If the person telling the story is back at the time (in their mind), they'll use the continuous. If they aren't, they won't.